# Adding Weeks to Current Date in Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, date

How can a given number of weeks be added to the current date in Excel 2007?  For example, if I need to add 12 weeks to the current date, 12/6/2010, how can that be done?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`=TODAY() + 7*12`

or in general,

`=TODAY() + 7*(no of weeks)`

Comment: If you are getting a number instead of a date (like I was), change the cell formatting to `Date` type.

Comment: Tahnk you, your answer is appriciated even ten years after you gave it.